# Zoom Level - Google Maps, countries

Tags: java, google-maps

If you look at this page: https://banting.co.za/find-a-coach/

You will see the world map almost duplicates itself, it is a plugin, however
is there something simple I am missing to make the world map fit without it repeating?

/**
* All locations map scripts
*/
jQuery(function($){

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadmap();
});

function loadmap()
{
    var locations = wpsl_locator_all.locations;
    var mapstyles = wpsl_locator.mapstyles; 
    var mappin = ( wpsl_locator.mappin ) ? wpsl_locator.mappin : '';
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            mapTypeControl: false,
            zoom: 8,
            styles: mapstyles,
            panControl : false
        }
    if ( wpsl_locator.custom_map_options === '1' )  mapOptions = wpsl_locator.map_options;

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
    var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('alllocationsmap'), mapOptions );

    // Loop through array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < locations.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].latitude, locations[i].longitude);
        bounds.extend(position);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: locations[i].title,
            icon: mappin
        }); 

        // Info window for each marker 
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i){
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(locations[i].infowindow);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                wpsl_all_locations_marker_clicked(marker, infoWindow)
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Center the Map
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() { 
                if ( locations.length < 2 ) {
                map.setZoom(13);
            }
            google.maps.event.removeListener(listener); 
        });
    }

    // Fit the map bounds to all the pins
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

    wpsl_all_locations_rendered(map);

} // loadmap()
```

});

Comment: I would suggest you look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498210/display-world-map-with-no-repeats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to conserve a certain ratio between height and width.
Especially if your zoom level is this low.

I'll recommend you to fix at least your width to not 100%

Comment: I found this javascript though: